# beautifulsoup: Unable to get correct info from dividendinvestor with cookie

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get some data from dividendinvestor.com. But the content results did not have any information such as "Consecutive Dividend Increases".

Does anyone has a work around for this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.dividendinvestor.com/dividend-quote/intc/'
headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': f'{url}',
    'Cookie': 'seenslideup=1; seenpopup=1',
    'TE': 'Trailers'
}

print(str(BeautifulSoup(r_get.content, 'html.parser'))
```

Comment: What do you want to extract from the URL can you please more clear about it!

Comment: Hi, I like to got information such as "Consecutive Dividend Increases".

Comment: URL generates data dynamically so you can not scrape data using `bs4` but from Network tab i have found that it is render through ajax [URL](https://www.dividendinvestor.com/ajax/?action=quote_ajax&type=POST&nonce=ea2c75061e&symbol=INTC&user_type=visitor) you can make call to this URL but you need `regex` to get the data according to your need

Comment: I can get url to work with bs4 for other sites such as dividata and finviz but just not dividendinvestor. If I can see my data in the content, I can use regex.

Comment: i have posted my answer how you can find content in your URL by using URL that loads your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can get ajax request URL from Network tab which returns `json`
> data you can parse it to `bs4` and it returns HTML so you can extract
> what so ever data is needed!

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"}
res=requests.get("https://www.dividendinvestor.com/ajax/?action=quote_ajax&type=POST&nonce=ea2c75061e&symbol=INTC&user_type=visitor",headers=headers)


import json
data=json.loads(res.text)['html']
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,"lxml")
```

Output:

```
<html><body><h1>INTC:Intel Corp - Stock Price Quote and Dividend Data</h1>
<div id="overview">
<div id="overview-close">
<h2>INTC STOCK PRICE LATEST CLOSE</h2>
....
```

Comment: May I know how did you get the "https://www.dividendinvestor.com/ajax/?action=quote_ajax&type=POST&nonce=ea2c75061e&symbol=INTC&user_type=visitor" from the html? I tried to find from inspection and I can't seems to find it.

Comment: Go to Chrom developer Mode -> Network Tab -> Relaod your website and than in left hand site search will be there you can search element that you are looking for it will return link and you can click on that  -> go to preview -> copy URL -> and use python thats it!

Comment: Hi Bhavya, the above method was failing this week with res.text returning '{"error":"Nonce verification failed!"}', I checked the URL from Network Tab and the nouce has been changed to https://www.dividendinvestor.com/ajax/?action=quote_ajax&type=POST&nonce=7e8934e912&symbol=MSFT&user_type=visitor but this url still return Nouce verification fail. Do you happen to know what happened?